# simple questions on $TM$s runs lengths

Tags: computability, turing-machines

1. Is it possible that the number of running steps in $TM$ that runs on
   word $w$ will be $0$?
2. Is it possible that the number of running steps in $TM$ that runs on the empty word $\epsilon$ will be bigger than $0$ or $1$ (depends on the answer to question 1)?
3. Is it possible that the number of running steps in $TM$ that runs on the empty word $\epsilon$ will be infinity?

I am asking this because I'M little confused...

I think that the answers are:

1. no, because the $q_0$ and the $q_{accept} /q_{reject}$ are fully seperate states.

   2. yes, it is depends on the $TM$s definition.
   3. yes, it is depends on the $TM$s definition.

Comment: For 3, just create a TM with 2 states $q_0$ and $q_1$. When in $q_0$ the TM transitions to $q_1$ and when in $q_1$ the TM transitions to $q_0$. If (3) is possible, then clearly (2) is also possible.

Comment: thanks! what about (1)? I think the answer is "no" because always $q_0\neq q_{accept}$ and $q_0\neq q_{reject}$ (as I said $q_0$ is fully seperate from the 2 halting states and because of that the $TM$ must do at least 1 step before halting).

Comment: Yes, the TM must take at least 1 step to go from the initial state to one of the halting states.

Comment: thanks!! 
you helped me alot